# How to read parquet files directly from azure datalake without spark?

Tags: python, azure

I am new to Azure cloud and have some .parquet datafiles stored in the datalake, I want to read them in a dataframe (pandas or dask) using python. Is there a way to read the parquet files in python other than using spark? I do not want to download the data on my local machine but read them directly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i read a file from Azure Data Lake Gen 2 using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579841/how-can-i-read-a-file-from-azure-data-lake-gen-2-using-python)

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not use Spark, or using spark is the only way?

Comment: right click the file in azure storage explorer, get the SAS url, and use pandas `read.csv` on the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an efficient way to read parquet files into pandas dataframe in python, the code is as follows for anyone looking for an answer;

```
import azure.identity
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.fs
import pyarrowfs_adlgen2

handler=pyarrowfs_adlgen2.AccountHandler.from_account_name('YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME',azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential())

fs = pyarrow.fs.PyFileSystem(handler)

df = pd.read_parquet('container/dataset.parq', filesystem=fs)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can read parquet files directly using `read_parquet()`. Here is a sample that worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
source ='<Your Blob SAS URL>'
df = pd.read_parquet(source)
print(df)
```

**Output :**

[image]

**REFERENCES :**
[Read file from Azure Blob storage to directly to data frame using Python](https://thisismeetpatel.medium.com/read-csv-file-from-azure-blob-storage-to-directly-to-data-frame-using-python-83d34c4cbe57)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out a way using pd.read_parquet(path,filesytem) to read any file in the blob.